# Can a customer save their cart to an invoice?

Tags: cartthrob

We have a client whose shipping needs are complicated enough that they currently only allow checkout for customers with their own shipping accounts.  They would like to be able to open up their checkout process to allow purchases where the customer may not have their own shipping account.

I don't have any experience with CartThrob Invoice, which seems like it may make it possible for our client to create an invoice and add their own shipping cost.  But would it be possible for a customer to somehow save their order as an invoice?  Or maybe use the Save Order payment gateway, and then convert that saved order into an invoice so the shipping could be updated?

Comment: Just to clarify, the user would place an order (kind of), but not get charged until a later time when your client would put in their shipping charge, and the customer would come back to add their credit card info and finalize based on the new total. Is that correct? I have a few ideas but want to make sure I'm understanding the flow.

Comment: @Matt: Yes, this is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for providing the information in the comment above. Unfortunately I don't think there's a built-in way to programmatically do this. However, the `exp_cartthrob_invoice_table` is pretty straightforward. You should consider an extension that fires after an order is placed (potentially via the "offline payments" or "Save Order" gateways) that takes their info and `INSERT`s a row into `exp_cartthrob_invoice_table`.

Here's the structure of that table:

```
CREATE TABLE `exp_cartthrob_invoice_table` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `inv_description` text,
  `inv_title` text,
  `inv_line_items` text,
  `inv_cost` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inv_total_hours` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inv_status` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inv_date` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inv_paid_date` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inv_email_address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inv_member_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inv_order_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inv_reference_number` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inv_first_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inv_last_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inv_company` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inv_address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inv_address2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inv_city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inv_state` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inv_zip` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inv_country_code` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inv_phone` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=103 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And here's a sample row. The `inv_line_items` column is a `base64_encode()`d JSON object.

```
INSERT INTO `exp_cartthrob_invoice_table` (`id`, `inv_description`, `inv_title`, `inv_line_items`, `inv_cost`, `inv_total_hours`, `inv_status`, `inv_date`, `inv_paid_date`, `inv_email_address`, `inv_member_id`, `inv_order_id`, `inv_reference_number`, `inv_first_name`, `inv_last_name`, `inv_company`, `inv_address`, `inv_address2`, `inv_city`, `inv_state`, `inv_zip`, `inv_country_code`, `inv_phone`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Test Invoice', 'Test Invoice', 'YToxOntpOjA7YTo0OntzOjEwOiJpdGVtX3RpdGxlIjtzOjQ6InRlc3QiO3M6MTY6Iml0ZW1fZGVzY3JpcHRpb24iO3M6NDoidGVzdCI7czo1OiJob3VycyI7aToyO3M6OToiaXRlbV9jb3N0IjtpOjI1MDt9fQ==', '250', '2', 'pending', 1382031430, NULL, 'test@test.com', 0, NULL, '', 'John', 'Smith', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '');
```

Feel free to contact us at support@cartthrob.com if you'd like help implementing this!

Comment: Thanks @Matt! At the moment, we haven't yet purchased the license for Invoice, so I'm unable to see what the table structure looks like. Is there any way to play around with it and get a feel for what it offers before purchasing?  Or possibly provide a few screenshots, including the DB table with some sample data?

Comment: @jrrdnx I just edited the comment to add the table structure and a sample row.

Comment: Thanks again! I've provided an overview to our client and it sounds like it's a viable solution.  I'll definitely contact you if we need any assistance.